# How to open .XLS in excel viewer without changing default program?

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice

I have two excel .XLS files. We need one of the files to be opened using Excel Viewer and the other is being opened using OpenOffice. the file using excel viewer cannot be edited hence using the viewer. Is there anyway to set this up? I can change the default program but it changes it for all XLS files. Yes I can right click open with and select Excel Viewer, however this will be on the manufacturing shop floor where users aren't the most computer savvy.

Answer (score 1):

**Double-click file from Explorer solution**

If you really want double-click-from-explorer type functionality, the only way would be to save one of the files in another spreadsheet file format. Depending on the Excel viewer compatibility, you might want to try saving it as old .xls (pre 2007 I think) vs. the newer .xlsx files. You should be able to tell windows to always use say the viewer for .xls and openoffice for .xlsx. You can try several other file types in the "save as type" drop down, like .xlsb, .csv, .ods, .prn, .xml.

**Dedicated open-this-file-with-viewer shortcut solution**

Another option is to create a shortcut for the viewer app on the desktop. To do this navigate to the viewer executable in c:\program files... (some path), then right-click > Send to > Desktop (create shortcut). Now go to the desktop, right-click the new shortcut > properties and edit the target field. Add the path and filename for the file you want to open in the viewer app in double quotes next to the executable in Target e.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Viewer\view32.exe" "C:\temp\readonlyspreadsheet.xls"
```

Go back to the shortcut on the desktop, right-click > rename and call the shortcut "View readonlyspreadsheet.xls" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking on the file in explorer, FIRST open the excel viewer program, then inside the program click on the "Open" symbol, and choose the file you need to open from the dialogue box.

Comment: Yes that will work however, asking a user to do that on the shop floor every time they want to use the file will cause some issues. Is there anyway to make a shortcut on the desktop?

Comment: Why don't you pin the program to the taskbar? Once it's open, right-click the program's icon on the taskbar and select "pin to taskbar". Or, if you want to create a desktop shortcut, [see this article](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/make-desktop-shortcuts-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows itself more easily than just about anything else. You just need a short script. Those files used to be called Batch files but now are also called Command files or Script files.

Strictly speaking, they are a kind of script file and you may have access to one you'd prefer and which may be on the computers on the shop floor as many shop control programs load one during install.

In any case, you can replace the obvious material in the following:

```
@echo off
cls

start YourExcelViewerProgram C:\Users\You\Documents\YourFirstExcelFile.xls
start YourOpenOfficeSpreadsheetProgram C:\Users\You\Documents\YourSecondExcelFile.xls

exit
```

Run like this, the command window goes away when the batch file has run. Your two programs for opening the particular files will launch and it will end.

Open Notepad and paste the above into it, then save it with some acceptable filename.

To make it simple for everyone, including folks who have no interest, or, to be fair, no need for an interest (well, not much so long as someone nice comes along and solves their problem like you are about to), you then create a shortcut for the command file and drag it onto the Task Bar. Or, for that matter, just drag the file onto it.

Or place it somewhere acceptable on their desktop/s and all they need to do to open the files as desired is to click (or double click, depending on their settings) on it and both files will open in the right programs, ready for use.

Lots of other ways, but I think this fills the bill best. In addition to all the other advantages, EVERY computer that you have has the ability to run the command file built right in.

Give it a name with the `.bat` extension and it will work on the oldest you could possibly have running. Even the extension `.cmd` will run on just about anything you could possibly have.

Unless you have Apple's desktops and laptops. But then, Apple surely has a comparable way. Of course, that chance is low as no one loving Apple would sully a precious Apple computer by placing it on a factory floor! So no worries!